# dc.js line chart is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using third party API to render some data in the table. In the table, I need to show the user a line chart. I am using dc.js to draw a chart.

But Somehow It is not creating a chart.

input JSON object :

```
coinData.histoday = [
  {
    "time": 1542240000,
    "high": 0.5026,
    "low": 0.4693,
    "open": 0.4917,
    "volumefrom": 34761.89,
    "volumeto": 16974.23,
    "close": 0.4883
  },
  ...
  {
    "time": 1542326400,
    "high": 0.4996,
    "low": 0.4616,
    "open": 0.483,
    "volumefrom": 18359.92,
    "volumeto": 8816.43,
    "close": 0.4802
  }
]
```

Javascript code :

```
        var ndx = crossfilter(coinData.histoday),
        dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            var myDate = new Date( d.time *1000);
            return myDate;
        }),
        dateGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return d.close;
        }),
        priceDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            var myDate = new Date( d.time *1000);
            return myDate;
        }),
        priceGroup = priceDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
            return d.close;
        });

        lineChart.width(100)
            .height(40)
            .dimension(priceGroup)
            .group(dateGroup)
            .margins({left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
            .brushOn(true)
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,20]));

        dc.renderAll();
```

You can see the code at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Hardik158/L9vj37ef/3/)

Comment: you work with dates on the x-axis but you have a scaleLinear with a fixed domain of [6,20]

Comment: @rioV8 Actually I have picked it from Example given for line chart. I tried to find a meaning of it but I didn't find any proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I hard code a `scaleTime().domain()` I see a line

```
.x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1542240000*1000),new Date(1542844800*1000)]));
```

You should determine it based on the `histoday` values.